# python unicode formatting from SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am extracting MySQL data with Python like below. But I get characters like below. I don't want the data types, just the values - can I do it?

```
[[u'Fri', Decimal('3004043')], [u'Mon', Decimal('1450340')], [u'Sat', Decimal('1670562')], [u'Sun', Decimal('2373750')], [u'Thu', Decimal('3116066')], [u'Tue', Decimal('729403')
```

Here is the query

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT day, sum(interactionCount) as ic FROM tw_posts group by day")

posts = []
for x in mycursor:
  day = x[0]
  ic = x[1]
  inner = [day, ic]
  posts.append(inner)

print(posts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```